# Why record disappear when I update() it after using find_one?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

here is my code:

```
temp = haha.find_one({"fname" : name })

haha.update({"fname" : name } , {"time" : now()})
```

then the record "temp" disappear in the database,I was really confusing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic mistake made by many :), you REPLACED the document with `{"time" : now()}`, you need to use `$set`:

```
haha.update({"fname" : name } , {"$set":{"time" : now()}})
```